# I want to change the x-axis scientific notation from e-05 to e-06

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted some values from my experiment output by the spider(anaconda). I want to change x axis scientific notation from 1e-05 to 1e-06. I googled and could not find a relevant solution to this problem. please help

```
enter code here
```

#Import Libraries

```
import numpy as np 
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import style


#Handling value error
def isfloat(num):
    try:
        float(num)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
#import csv file
with open( 'try1.csv', 'r') as i:
    file01= list(csv.reader(i,delimiter=','))[2:]
    file02=[[float(k) if (isfloat(k)) else 0 for k in j] for j in file01] # Picking the values only
   
#creating a mumpy array    
        
Data= np.array(file02, dtype=float)
xdata= Data[:,0][::280]
ydata= Data[:,1][::280]

#Plot
plt.figure(1,dpi=800)
plt.title('Force Spectroscopy')
plt.ylabel('Vertical Deflection')
plt.xlabel('Measured Height')
plt.style.use(['seaborn_grid'])
plt.plot(xdata,ydata, color='green',label=('Experimental data'))

#Theoritical Plot
new= -(0.107e-5)*xdata
plt.plot(xdata,new, color= 'purple',label='Theoritical')

#Legend Modification
plt.legend('upper right',fontsize=20)
plt.legend()
```

[Output image of my plot. see the axis notation 1e-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnxje.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ticklabel_format()` to set the tick label format. You can add the following line -> `plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(-6,-6))` to your code to have the x-axis in e-06. Note that the -6 to -6 is telling matplotlib to set the format from e-06 to e-06. More info [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html)

Your modified code sample here to demonstrate the same...

**Code**

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import style

xdata = np.array([1.21, 1.32, 2.54]) * (1e-5)
ydata = [1, 4, 15]

#Plot
plt.figure(1,dpi=800)
plt.title('Force Spectroscopy')
plt.ylabel('Vertical Deflection')
plt.xlabel('Measured Height')

plt.plot(xdata,ydata, color='green',label=('Experimental data'))

#Theoritical Plot
new= -(0.107e-5)*np.array(xdata)
plt.plot(xdata,new, color= 'purple',label='Theoritical')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(-6,-6))

#Legend Modification
plt.legend('upper right',fontsize=20)
plt.legend()
```

**Output**

[image]